# Filling dataframe columns based on ranges described in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a very interesting problem here, I have a dataset like,

```
    id,    start,  end   
    1234    200   400
    1235    300   500
    1236    100   900
    1236    200   1200
    1236    300   1400
```

**Main Objective** : I want to count the number of concurrent sessions for each id.

```
at 100, id:1236 has 1 session running
at 200, id:1236 has 2 sessions
at 300, id:1236 has 3 sessions
...
at 1000m id:1236 has 2 sessions
etc
```

**My solution** :

- Add columns from 1 to 1400 (min and max of sessions) to all rows
- fill the columns between session start value and session end value with 1
- then add all the rows of the user so to get the above result.

**In pandas** :

```
df = pd.read_csv(data+fileName,sep="\t",usecols=[0,1,2],names=['id','start','end'])

for i in range(0,1440):
    df[str(i)]=0

print df.columns
```

I could add the columns and was thinking **how to fill 1 to these columns between session start and end in each row**. Each row can have different session start and end.

Any hint would help a lot. I am just trying it in pandas, but later *I have to port it to Apache pyspark where there is no pandas in worker nodes*.

Comment: In Pandas you could also do this: `df[(df.start <= t)&(df.end >= t)].groupby("id").count()['start'].reset_index()` where `t` is your desired time. Just rename the final column accordingly. But I don't know if this can be ported over the pyspark.

Comment: Thank you @Khris, indeed its a nice approach. here I will have to loop from 1 to 1400 to get the result hence processor intensive and my approach looks memory intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas you could also do this: 
`df[(df.start <= t)&(df.end >= t)].groupby("id").count()['start'].reset_index()`

where t is your desired time. Just rename the final column accordingly. But I don't know if this can be ported over the pyspark.@Khris